# PostfixAdmin not accepting .int Top-Level Domain

Tags: postfix, tld

I was requested to configure a new e-mail server and provide a Management WebUI for it (I selected **PostfixAdmin**), in a Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.

We need to support e-mail addresses with the format `...@<project-domain>.int`, let's say `@projectname.int`, due to it is required for an internal project (not connected to the Internet) on development.

I configured the e-mail, added `projectname.int` to my the server and workstation hostfiles (not in the DNS yet), ping it to check, added working clients from these other workstations.

But on PostfixAdmin setup, in the step to create a "superadmin account", when I  use an existing (and well tested) postfix email `admin@projectname.int` it does not work, it says "Admin is not a valid email address! Email address" (screenshot below).

Later, with testing purposes, I tried with `admin@projectname.com`, and it works, so, so, I wonder if maybe some TLDs, as **.int**, are not allowed for some reason, or if it is something else.

Do you have any idea about which problem it could be, or, if not allowed, about how I can allow my postfixadmin to use `.int`?

- Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
- MySQL 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25
- postfix 3.1.0-3
- dovecot 2.2.22 (fe789d2)
- apache2 2.4.18
- postfixadmin 3.2 (tar.gz downloaded from sourceforge)

  - configured as pointed out in the INSTALL.TXT instructions

My hostfile, /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1 projectname.int mailsrv.projectname.int mailsrv 

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

[image]

Comment: If you have access to `config.inc.php` (as a bit of a heavy-handed solution) you may wish to try changing `$CONF['emailcheck_resolve_domain']='YES';` to `$CONF['emailcheck_resolve_domain']='NO';`.

Comment: perfect, it was exactly that, thank you very much. If you post it as a main answer, I will select your answer as a valid solution

Comment: Warning: Do not attempt to make up domain names if you connect this system to the Internet. Use your actual registered domain name. If the fake domain name gets registered later, you will have a lot of trouble ahead of you.

Comment: of course, as I mentioned, it is for an internal project, therefore, internal use.
Thank you for the advice anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid domain which is resolvable by your nameserver(s) is typically necessary in this instance. However, if you have access to the configuration files for Postfix Admin, you may wish to try changing the line:

`$CONF['emailcheck_resolve_domain']='YES';`

to:

`$CONF['emailcheck_resolve_domain']='NO';`

in `config.inc.php` to bypass this particular error.